# Delaying formula execution in Excel to populate secondary sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a workbook that has the first sheet populated from another application similar function as a mail merge.  When the company field is empty I would like the Quote form on the second sheet to use the first and last name fields (concatenated) from sheet one.  I have also tried formating `A1,A2,A3,A4` as text.  Tried `isempty`, `istext` with combinations of Trim, Len all with no results.  If the data is populated from top to bottom and left to right will I need to use a macro to wait for the data to be populated before I can run formulas?

Thanks in advance,

**Example:**

```
Sheet 1
A1 [Company Name]
A2 [First Name]
A3 [Last Name]
A4 =concatenate(A2," ",A3)
A5 =IF(ISBLANK(A1),A4,A1)

Sheet 2
A15 ='Sheet 1'!$A5
```

Comment: This article should help you out. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx Specifically the part about using Volatile

Comment: Why do you think you need to wait before running formulas? When the data changes, the formulas will update immediately. What is the problem?

Comment: Really don't know what is your actual problem :(

Comment: I figured it out.  I cannot use a formula type like an if statement on the first sheet.  When I move the formula to the second sheet it works... strange but it only took 8 hours of different approaches....

Answer (score 1):

By placing the if statement on the second sheet I got the correct results.

In the Example place the formula on Sheet 2, A15=IF(ISBLANK(A1),A4,A1) verses referencing the result as in the example.